# How to add number in dynamic object's fields and remove empty fields using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

**INPUT:**

```
let counts = { first_counts: 10, second_counts: 20, third_counts: 0 };
```

**BRIEF:**

- I have object and all fields/keys are dynamic
- Add/plus 10 to each field/key's value
- Remove empty fields/keys
- I want to do it using [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash)

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

```
{ first_counts: 20, second_counts: 30 }
```

**WORKING CODE USIGN `FOR` AND `IF`:**

```js
let counts = { first_counts: 10, second_counts: 20, third_counts: 0 };
let newCounts = {};
for (let k in counts) {
  if (counts[k]) newCounts[k] = counts[k] + 10;
}
console.log(newCounts);
// result: { "first_counts": 20, "second_counts": 30 }
```

Is there any function to do this easily in **lodash**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make that `chain`ed (to help making one-liner). First filter key-value pairs which have falsy value. Finally map values and add 10 to each

```js
const counts = { first_counts: 10, second_counts: 20, third_counts: 0 };

const res = _.chain(counts)
  .pickBy(Boolean)
  .mapValues((v) => v + 10)
  .value();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce you can do that.

```
 const counts = { first_counts: 10, second_counts: 20, third_counts: 0 };

_.reduce(counts,(result, value, key) => {
  if(value) result[key] = value + 10;
  return result;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

one line solution

```
let counts = { first_counts: 10, second_counts: 20, third_counts: 0 };

let newCounts = _.reduce(counts, (r, v, k)=> v ? {...r, [k]: v + 10} : r, {});
```

```
r - result,
v - value,
k - key
```